Manufacturer's boot logo aspect ratio failure
I've seen this for many years with different Ubuntu versions. Right now 24.10
A computer may display "Asus" logo or "Dell" just fine during the GRUB part of boot. later in the boot, when the "Ubuntu 20 years" logo appears the aspect ratio of the vendor is horizontally squished.
Same malformed logo is displayed on shutdown.
note: This never happens on a newly installed system, but seems to appear after first release upgrade.
How to correct it?

No questions asked, so why not file a bug report?

True, added obvious question: how to correct t?"

filed bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/plymouth/+bug/2085507
